# Domo Rigato - in what way?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A popular yiddishe song incorporates the following refrain:

"Domo Rigato, Mister Roboto!"

Now, the correct pronunciation of the second word is actually ***"arigato."*** This means the famous refrain translates as follows:

"His likeness is as his weaving, Mister Roboto."

What aspect of his likeness is being compared to woven cloth, and how does this affect our treatment of the aforementioned Rav Roboto?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

He's someone who needed somewhere to hide to keep him alive.

[That is, he's a fox.](/a/55448)

Now, a fox crept; a fox hid; a fox stole is sometimes worn instead of woven cloth, which explains the connection. We learn from here not to be members of PETA.

Comment: But [what does the fox say?](http://youtu.be/jofNR_WkoCE)

Answer (score 1):

Your question stems from a mistaken pronunciation. The correct pronunciation is not דומו but דמו -- his blood is like his weaving. Since ["my blood is boiling"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/styx/mrroboto.html), it follows "my weaving is boiling". What does boiling have to do with weaving? To obtain dye to dye the cloth.

"I'm just a man who needed someone, and somewhere to hide To keep me alive" -- he's dying.