# Does the oven have a nose and more than one eye?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the Mishnah, Seder Teharot, Mesechet Calim, in 8:3, talking about an oven, it states:

> ואין לה גפים,

It doesn't have גפים, which K'hati explains to mean

> היינו אזניים

These are ears.

And we know it has a mouth, otherwise how would it talk to the water in the next mishna?

> ...הרי זה אומר: מטמאיך

The oven is talking to the water, saying that the water made it tamay. So obviously it has a mouth.

And, in the beginning of mishna ז, it says:

> ...השרץ שנמצא בעין של תנור

This translates to

> The *Sheretz* that is found in the eye of the oven... (My own translation)

So we know it has no ears, yes mouth, and yes one eye. Does it have another eye and a nose?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score -1):

The oven was Egypt, by which the eyes, nose, and mouth appear.

We read in Torah the following -

> [**Devarim 4:19-20**](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9968#v=19&showrashi=true) (Chabad)
>   <sup>19</sup> And lest you lift up your **eyes** to heaven, and see the sun, and the moon, and the stars, all the host of heaven, which the Lord your God assigned to all peoples under the entire heaven, and be drawn away to prostrate yourselves before them and worship them. <sup>20</sup> **But the Lord took you and brought you out of the iron crucible, out of Egypt, to be a people of His possession, as of this day.**

Jeremiah the prophet amplifies this passage from Torah as follows -

> [**Yirmiyahu 11:3-4**](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16008#v=3&showrashi=true) (Chabad)
>   <sup>3</sup> And you shall say to them, so said the Lord God of Israel; Cursed be the man who will not **hearken** to the **words** of this covenant, <sup>4</sup> Which I commanded your forefathers on the day I took them out of the land of Egypt, **out of the iron furnace,** saying: **Hearken** to **My voice** and do them, according to all that I will command you, and you shall be to Me for a people, and I will be to you for a God.

In this sense, the revelation and understanding of Torah came through the oven of Egypt, which communicates with ears, eyes, and nose (fire is seen and smelled). Rashi indicates in his comment of [Devarim 4:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9968#v=19&showrashi=true) that the "**כּוּר**" is a vessel or crucible in which the Gold is refined.

Thus understanding of Torah comes through the oven of Egypt, which communicates through the eyes, nose, and mouth.

Answer (score -5):

Point of order - We often talk about Pi hatanur, so we have direct reference to an oven having a mouth.

Additionally, the mishnah says it doesn't have ears ***plural,*** mashmah that it has a ***single*** ear rather than two.

We know that Hashem at times will react with "Charon Af" (Dvarim 11:17), which translates to "fiery nose." Now, the nose of a dragon may contain fire, but Hashem doesn't look like a dragon! Since we are created in his image, Hashem's image must be that of a man. So how can he have a fiery nose?

It must be that his nose is an oven!

But then how are we created in his image?

Hashem is really being nidmeh to a robot with a furnace for a head, which looks like an android i.e.: human in appearance! (See the first Thor movie for a rough illustration.) [image]

So why was man not created in this manner? He wishes for us to acheive this level of self perfection independently - "Ma'asei yadie lehit-Fire" - "It is for my handiwork to make themselves a flaming visage."

Since Hashem has human form, He has eyes, ears, nose, and mouth.

We already know that an oven has a nose, a mouth, and one ear, so we can use the din of holchin achar harov to tell us that it must have eyes as well!

QED.

Also, I may have inadvertently [answered my own question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55444/domo-rigato-in-what-way?s=1%7C1.5783), Mr. Roboto...

Comment: But the oven does NOT have ears... (See above.)

Comment: @Aeelnpprsu fixed that in my proof. it doesn't have TWO ears, but that means it must have ONE. Otherwise it would have said "doesn't even have ***an*** ear."

Comment: There's a fine line between silly and blasphemy. Calling Hashem a robot is possibly worse than assuming his creation of us in his image means he has some type of form. Even if this is all in jest. Imho.

Comment: @user6591 I understand and appreciate your concern. Granted that mainstream Judaism presently doesn't accept corporeality, that wasn't always the case. Many commentators debated this before the Rambam issued his now definitive opinion.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, It's probably not a great topic to joke about, though.

Comment: @isaacKotlicky bordering on blasphemy is not something you want to play with in Purim Torah even if supported by peripheral rishonim..that's close to gilui panim ..

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/can-purim-torah-be-heretical

Comment: Ok I was mekayem tochacha. Now I'm hoping you will delete and or edit your answer

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky honestly, had you just joked about corporeality I'm not sure i would have piped up, whether or not i should is a different issue. There was just something about calling Him a robot and the furnace head thing etc that just seemed past the point of funny.

Comment: @user6591 I have edited the answer to be clear that this is a nidmeh, not a corporeality. I have also added a source for this. Hopefully this skirts around the issue of corporeality enough to avoid conflict.

Comment: I agree. If you wanted to use Rabbeinu Tam's opinion in a Purim Torah, I wouldn't say anything -- I even try to keep my mouth shut when people use his opinion seriously! I just feel like I have to say in my personal opinion the robot joke was in poor taste especially for a work day a week before Purim when most of us are still sober.